# Orcale Java SE Critical security Patches on the 7th, do I have to update Java all the Linux boxes that host our apps?

Tags: security, java

according to Oracle,
"All these vulnerabilities may be remotely exploitable without authentication, i.e., may be exploited over a network without the need for a username and password. "
Does this include our Java App that runs with Tomcat that is in production right now and visible to the internet ? (80 and 443).  Do I have to update Java JRE on all those server?

Or is this strictly an end-user update?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/javacpujune2011-313339.html  this is the link to the advisory.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/javacpujune2011-313339.html  here is the advisory

Answer (score 1):

No, it also includes server side fixes, according to the Oracle Technote it says:

> This Critical Patch Update contains 17
>   new security fixes for Oracle Java SE
>   - **5 apply to client and server** deployments of Java SE, 11 apply to
>   client deployments of Java SE only,
>   and **1 applies to server** deployments of
>   Java SE only

The one that applies to servers only is in NIO (Networking), and the other 5 are in Java 2D and Java Sound Components.